# php upload file using cURL causing infinite loop

Tags: php, html, curl

i'm using an update button on an HTML page to get the values of a table and then i'm just putting those values on a .csv file.
I want to use my already existing upload form to post the newly generated file .csv.
This is the first part of the code called by the update button:

```
<?php

$PATH = "ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/FOLDER";
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $Data = $_POST['data']['arrayHTML'];
        $id = $_POST['data']['id'];
        $filename = $PATH.$id."_".date('Ymd').".csv";
        $fileHandler = fopen($filename, "w");
        $splittedArray = array_chunk($Data, 4);
        fputcsv($fileHandler, array("EAN", "REC", "RETAIL", "BRAND DISCOUNT"), ";");
        foreach ($splittedArray as $line) {
            fputcsv($fileHandler, $line, ";");
        }
        fclose($fileHandler);
        echo "Done!";
    }
}
```

This is the HTML upload form:

```
<table border="1" align="center" width="800px;">
    <form METHOD="POST" ACTION="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr><td>
        <h5><h3><b>Sync file:</b></h3><input type="file" name="fichero">
        <input type=text name="lateupdate" value='.date("Y-m-d").' id="datepicker">
        <input type=hidden name="carpeta" value="ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/UPLOAD/FOLDER/">
        <input type=hidden name="page" value="index.php"/>
        <input type=hidden name="id" value="'.$idprov.'"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
```

Ok so, once the csv file generated, i'm using cURL like this:

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath($filename);
$cfile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
$target_url = "http://localhost:8000/upload.php";
$post = array('id'=>$id, 'file'=>$cfile, 'lateupdate'=>date('Y-m-d'), 'carpeta'=>'PATH/TO/FOLDER', 'page'=>'index.php');
//Iniating cURL
$ch = curl_init();
//setting the options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

And i'm obtaining an infinte loop on my localhost server.

So i tried with:

```
exec("curl -X POST -F 'fichero=@$filename' -F 'page=index.php'\
      -F 'carpeta=/srv/http/TradeinnDev/killred/upload/'\ 
      -F 'lateupdate=".date('Y-m-d')."' \
      -F'id=$id' http://localhost:8000/upload.php"
    );
```

And this is the output of my localhost server log:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t /srv/http/
PHP 7.1.6 Development Server started at Wed Jun 28 10:00:35 2017
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /srv/http/
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Jun 28 10:00:38 2017] ::1:54168 [200]: /index.php?id=1
[Wed Jun 28 10:00:38 2017] ::1:54174 [200]: /css/menu_style.css
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   878    0     0  100   878      0      8  0:01:49  0:01:41  0:00:08     0^C
```

I have to kill it as the TIME LEFT field is always reseting.

Thank you for your help

*******************EDIT***********************************

This is the weird behaviour of the uploading proccess:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   777    0     0  100   777      0    387  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   388
100   777    0     0  100   777      0    258  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   258
100   777    0     0  100   777      0    193  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   194
100   777    0     0  100   777      0    110  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     97  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     64  0:00:12  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     25  0:00:31  0:00:30  0:00:01     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     22  0:00:35  0:00:34  0:00:01     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     19  0:00:40  0:00:40 --:--:--     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     18  0:00:43  0:00:41  0:00:02     0
100   777    0     0  100   777      0     11  0:01:10  0:01:10 --:--:--     0
```

Comment: the code shown doesn't actually contain any loop constructs. It's hard to see what could be causing an infinite loop (if that is indeed the problem). Are you saying that the cURL request times out in both cases? What happens if you make a request to that URL using a different tool such as POSTMAN or SOAPUI?

Comment: i have tried with cURL in command line using the exact same syntax as in the exec call and it's working fine, but using it in PHP doesn't. i've called it infinite loop just because cURL execution never stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, passing the php.ini file in argument of the php built-in webserver command line is the solution, like this:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t /srv/http/TradeinnDev/killred -c /etc/php/php.ini
```

From the man page of PHP:

```
--php-ini path|file
       -c path|file   Look for php.ini file in the directory path or use the specified file
```